# If there are no Abstract classes, why do they refer to them in the documentation?

Tags: objective-c, swift, abstract-class

I was looking through the Apple documentation on the `UICollectionViewLayout` and saw this:

> An **abstract** base class for generating layout information for a collection view.

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout)

As you can see, they refer to this as an abstract class, and yet, there are questions like this littered all over SO:

[Abstract class in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41991643/abstract-class-in-swift)

[Abstract classes in Swift Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24110396/abstract-classes-in-swift-language)

In all of these, the answers say that there is no concept of "abstract class" in Objective-C or Swift.

If this is true, why do they continuously refer to it?

Comment: Technically there is nothing like abstract. So it will not give you errors if you don't override the methods or use it as it is. But you will achieve nothing by doing so. It would be futile to use it as it is.

Comment: I know it is hard for us developers to understand that "abstract" is also a word in the real world and not only for classes :) I think they not referring to abstract, they just using the word like it is normally used.

Comment: There _is_ a **concept** of "abstract" in ObjC and Swift, as your research has demonstrated. It's just not the exact meaning that it has in other languages, such as Java (just like the word "primitive" doesn't have _exactly_ the same meaning). What is it that you're looking for that isn't answered by the questions you've linked and others like them?

Comment: Additionally, you're asking about a class that's implemented in ObjC, but linking to SO questions about Swift. The two languages have very different semantics in many areas, and Swift's first-class protocols (especially given default implementations), compared to ObjC's, are one of them.

Comment: @JoshCaswell regarding your comment on Swift vs Obj-C, the documentation uses the same phrasing for both languages.

Comment: The doc was originally written when there was no Swift, and other than method signatures, they don't seem to be interested in editing Swift-specific stuff in.

Answer (score 1):

True, there are no abstract classes in Swift, the closest representation would be protocols.

But in this particular case *abstract class* means that you're not supposed to use `UICollectionViewLayout` class yourself - either subclass it to provide a custom layout and behaviour, or use `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` (which inherits from `UICollectionViewLayout`) if you want the default layout.

Comment: While I can understand that, it find it odd that they would allow me to instantiate an object that they dont want me to. This from the same language that removed `++` because they were afraid that people would get confused by `++x` and `x++`?

Comment: That's because `UICollectionViewLayout` is an Objective-C class and in Objective-C there are no access modifiers. So I suppose that the only option to prevent you from initializing it would be to rewrite entire UIKit to pure Swift.

Comment: @DavidPilkington From the documentation: "You must subclass UICollectionViewLayout in order to use it." It's abstract for that reason, if you don't subclass it and provide the necessary implementations for the methods then it doesn't do much. So it's abstract in the sense that it's useless without a specialized implementation.